# Python GDAL changing geotransform without opening as numpy array

Tags: gdal

My raster is upside down, but it is too large to open as an array and rewrite it with a different geotransformation. Do you know a way to change the geotransformation without opening the raster as a numpy array?

my normal approach

```
import gdal
import numpy
r = gdal.Open(fileLocation)
band = r.GetRasterBand(1)  # bands start at one
b = band.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float16)
dst_ds = driver.Create(output_file, band.XSize, band.YSize, 1, gdal.GDT_Int16)
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(a)
```

Comment: As far as I know, you shouldn't have to re-write the array to modify the geotransform.  Have you tried omitting the last line and just modifying the geotransform that you're setting in the 2nd to last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough for changing the geotransformation (captured from GDAL autotests https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gcore/tiff_write.py):

```
ds = gdal.Open('tmp/tiff57.tif', gdal.GA_Update)
ds.SetGeoTransform([100, 1, 3, 200, 3, 1])
ds = None
```